# Linker error in C. while using <graphics.h> Turbo C++

Tags: c++, c, linker, turbo-c++, bgi

I have entered the following code in *turbo c++*.

```
    #include<graphics.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    int main()
    {
    int gd= DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"D:\\TC\\BGI");
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
    }
```

It compiles without any errors and warning. But when I run the program the following errors are displayed

> - Linker Error: Undefined symbol_closegraph in module G1.C
> - Linker Error: Undefined symbol_initgraph in module G1.C

note : The BGI folder is in the path D:\TC\

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You need to link against `graphics.lib`, and you should probably consider switching to a more recent compiler

Comment: Please edit the title and add Turbo C to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Turbo C .. just need to check one option:

Go to `Options->Linker->Libraries` and check the Graphics Library option

Comment: hahahaha, love that you remember this, lol. Apparently people still use TC, Borland should be proud :P

Comment: @adrin yeah.. stopped using this now but I know I too got trouble using it :D

Comment: @Digital_Reality:sad no one find this question useful... :( thank you for the answer sir :)

Comment: @Digital_Reality sir in output i got the message " Graphics not initialized use ('initgraph') .  What should I do ???

Comment: @MELWIN Err.. time changes buddy! :) We have to stick to it.. Anyway when are you moving to new compiler? :D

Comment: Um.. I am not sure what might be solution.. but check this link http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/76092/bgi-error-graphics-not-initializeduse-initgraph

Answer (score 3):

Go to `options>>linker>>libraries` and instead of:

```
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"");
```

Write:

```
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"..\\BGI);
```